# How do you make conda deactivate work in hpc?

Tags: macos, conda, hpc

When I typed `conda deactivate`, it will exit. But when I logged into my account in hpc next time, it will automatically become base again. Does that mean that the previous `conda deactivate` is not working? Same thing happens to my Mac. Does anyone know how to resolve this in hpc? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The environment activation (and deactivation) is not persistent across different shell sessions. If you wish to disable auto-activation of **base** altogether, then set

```bash
conda config --set auto_activate_base false
```

If you wish to persist a shell session, then look into using `screen` or `tmux`. Personally, I'd recommend `screen`; there are known issues with environment variable management with `tmux` that interfere with how Conda manages environment activation.